# upcase and downcase for accented characters

Tags: ruby, special-characters, upcase

I'm a beginner working on a simple Ruby program to generate vocabulary lists from text files. Spanish allows words to carry stress marks on capitalized first letters (e.g. "Ábaco"), but I want all words in my list to be downcased. Right now, if I try `"Á".downcase` the console returns "Á".

Is there a way to use upcase & downcase in ruby with accented characters in Spanish (áéíóúñ)?

This is what my program presently looks like:

```
f = File.open(".../cat.txt")
words = f.read.split.map(&:downcase)
f.close
words = words.map {|item| item.gsub(/[,.?!-"'"]/, '')}
words = words.uniq.sort

File.open(".../catwords.txt", "w+") do |f|
  words.each { |element| f.puts(element) }
end
```

Comment: Ruby 2.4+ now supports more Unicode case mappings (upcase / downcase) and `"Á".downcase` now returns `"á"`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this sample code

```
our_string.tr('Á', 'á')
```

As per the documentation:

> (from ruby site)
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------   str.tr(from_str, to_str)   => new_str
>
> ---
>
> Returns a copy of str with the characters in from_str replaced by the
>   corresponding characters in to_str.  If to_str is shorter than
>   from_str, it is padded with its last character in order to maintain
>   the correspondence.
>
> `"hello".tr('el', 'ip')      #=> "hippo"`
>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You would need a library that understand language-specific rules for stuff like ordering and transformation. https://github.com/jchris/icu4r is probably the main one, but you'll find similar stuff if you search around for `ICU` (the standards project for this kind of thing).